# how to open JSON file from URL in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, google-maps, next.js

I'm trying to open a JSON file after uploading it to the server from a URL .. then parsing it and viewing its features of it inside google Maps.. but it is unable to open it as an error is being returned from "fs" lib.

here is my code :

```js
"use client"
import React from 'react'
import { GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader } from '@react-google-maps/api';
import { useState } from "react";
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js';
import { subaBaseURL, subaBaseKey,googleMapsApiKey } from './enums'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

const containerStyle = {
    width: '100',
    height: '400px'
};

const center = {
    lat: 29.95375640,
    lng: 31.53700030
};

function Map() {

    const [isUploadingFile, setIsUploadingFile] = useState(false)
    const [thefile, setTheFile] = useState([])
    const [theName, setTheName] = useState("")
    const [map, setMap] = React.useState(null)
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  
    const supabase = createClient(subaBaseURL, subaBaseKey);
  
  
    function toggleFileUploading() {
      setIsUploadingFile(!isUploadingFile)
    }
    function toggleLoading(){
        setIsLoading(!isLoading)
    }
  
    async function uploadShapeFile(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      toggleLoading()
      let myUUID = uuid();
      const finalFileName = `${myUUID}${theName}.json`;
      const { data, error } = await supabase.storage.from('kml_files').upload(`test/${theName}/${finalFileName}`, thefile)
      const publicUrl = supabase.storage.from('kml_files').getPublicUrl(`test/${theName}/${finalFileName}`)
      console.log(publicUrl)
      createNewInput(publicUrl['data']['publicUrl'])
    }



    async function createNewInput(fileURL) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(fileURL);
        console.log(response)
        const geojsonData = await response.json();
        const file = await fs.readFile(geojsonData.url, 'utf8');
        const data = JSON.parse(file);
        console.log(data.geometryType)
        // Assuming the GeoJSON features are in the 'features' property
        const geojsonFeatures = geojsonData.features;
    
        // Use the map instance to add GeoJSON features
        if (map) {
          // Clear existing markers or layers if needed
          // For example: map.data.forEach(feature => map.data.remove(feature));
    
          // Add GeoJSON features to the map
          geojsonFeatures.forEach(feature => {
            const geometry = feature.geometry;
            const attributes = feature.attributes;
    
            // Create a new Google Maps Data layer feature
            const googleFeature = new window.google.maps.Data.Feature({
              geometry: new window.google.maps.Data.Polygon([geometry.rings]),
              properties: attributes,
            });
    
            // Add the feature to the map
            map.data.add(googleFeature);
          });
    
          // Automatically fit the map to the bounds of the GeoJSON features
          const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          map.data.forEach(feature => {
            feature.getGeometry().forEachLatLng(latLng => {
              bounds.extend(latLng);
            });
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error loading GeoJSON data:', error);
      }

    }

    const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
        id: 'google-map-script',
        googleMapsApiKey: googleMapsApiKey
    })


    const onLoad = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
        // This is just an example of getting and using the map instance!!! don't just blindly copy!
        const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds(center);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        setMap(map)
    }, [])

    const onUnmount = React.useCallback(function callback(map) {
        setMap(null)
    }, [])

    return isLoaded ? (
        <>
              {isUploadingFile &&
        <button onClick={toggleFileUploading} type="button" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 me-2 mb-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Upload new file </button>
      }
      {!isUploadingFile &&
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={uploadShapeFile}>
            <label for="file_name" class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">File name</label>
            <input type="text" id="file_name" class="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500" onChange={e => setTheName(e.target.value)} required />
            <br></br>
            <label class="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white" for="file_input">Upload file</label>
            <input class="block w-full text-sm text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg cursor-pointer bg-gray-50 dark:text-gray-400 focus:outline-none dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400" id="file_input" type="file" onChange={e => setTheFile(e.target.files[0])} required />
            <br></br>
            <button type="submit" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 me-2 mb-2 dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Upload</button>
            <button onClick={toggleFileUploading} type="button" class="text-white bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 me-2 mb-2 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:border-gray-700">Cancel</button>

          </form>
        </div>

      }
        <GoogleMap
            mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
            center={center}
            zoom={10}
            onLoad={onLoad}
            onUnmount={onUnmount}
        >
            { /* Child components, such as markers, info windows, etc. */}
            <></>
        </GoogleMap>

        </>
    ) : <></>
}

export default React.memo(Map)
```

and here is the error am getting :

```
./src/app/components/Map/Map.jsx:8:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
   6 | import { subaBaseURL, subaBaseKey,googleMapsApiKey } from './enums'
   7 | import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
>  8 | import { promises as fs } from 'fs';
   9 |
  10 | const containerStyle = {
  11 |     width: '100',

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/components/index.js
./src/app/page.js
```

Comment: You cannot use fs in client side, if you want to get the file you uploaded to the server you need to use fetch to get the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs` is a node library so you can't use it as-is in a Client Component. So you need to, either read your file differently or move some part to a Server Component or API route.

You probably can use `fetch` again instead of `fs` if it is a URL as the name would suggest or move json fetching and file reading to an API route.

Comment: Do you mean I can use fetch to read the content of the file without using fs and opening it?

Comment: If it is a proper URL then yes. You will a json that you can `await response.json()` and have your object parsed